# linq c# object ToDictionary

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

i am trying to write the query in linq and i am expecting x.key to add it to my dictionary and it does not show up . not sure how to proceed further . i went over other threads and could not find an example similar to this object . i am new to this and any help is much appreciated

```
if (emp.something != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in emp.something)
                {
                    if (item.Value.someId.AllowMultiple.Equals(false))
                    {
                        var ff = (singleObject) item.Value;
                        if (ff.Value != null)
                        {
                            Dict.Add((int)ff.Value, item.Key);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


            emp.something?.Where(x => x.Value.someId.AllowMultiple.Equals(false))
                .Select(y => (singleObject) y.Value)
                .ToDictionary(y => y.Value, x.
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code to review? IT would help to see what ```emp.something``` is, and since it's some form of collection it would be great to see the code for the objects in that collection. This info will help enormously in getting a better answer.

Comment: my apology Nik.  below linq works as expected. yea its a collection and value is an object with 2 property .nextime , i will post my questions clearly. Thanks for the quick reply and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ToDictionary` call is working with whatever is returns from the `Select` before is. Since in that method, you return the `Value` property, the collection processed by `ToDictionary` is the collection of `Value` values. In other words, it knows nothing of the `x` value in the previous commands. You'd have to include it in the projection to use it "downstream".

The equivalent to your loop seems to be :

```
emp.something?.Where(item => item.Value.someId.AllowMultiple.Equals(false)
              .Select(item => new {item, ff = (singleObject) item.Value} 
              .Where(x => x.ff.Value != null)
              .ToDictionary(x => (int)x.ff.Value, x => x.item.Key);
```

But the casts and nested `Values` make it confusing. If your loop works, I'd just stick with it - it will be much easier to debug, and the equivalent Linq query is much harder (in my opinion) to understand).

Comment: Did you test this before posting? The syntax for `.ToDictionary` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks very much. both linq and loop works as expected (yeah fixed the syntax in linq) . thanks for the explanation . now i understand the execution behind it